# Format and compare Dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do date comparison in javascript.Through a web service call I am getting a date in the form of ""2014-07-02T09:49:49.299Z" and from database I am getting the dat like "2014-07-11 16:01:34".I need to compare these two dates after doing some kind of formatting.i am not sure how to format these two kind of dates to a common format.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: yes I tried using Date object but the following code returns undefined  in my case var d1 = new Date("2014-07-02T09:49:49.299Z")

Comment: 2014-07-02T09:49:49.299Z, can you explain that format?

Comment: @abhijeet: I think that's the ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @MobX: I'm not sure what's going on, as the `Date` constructor should never return `undefined`.

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/EZ7AP/

Comment: See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309133/convert-net-date-time-format-string-to-javascript-date-time-format-string.

Comment: @ Juhana sorry my mistake its   var date1 = new Date("2014-07-11 16:01:34"); returned ""Invalid Date""

Comment: @MobX- Let us know, that what was your mistake

Comment: Hi , I have created these two objecs var date1 = new Date("2014-07-11 16:01:34");
                            var date2 = new Date("2014-07-02T09:49:49.299Z");.Here date1.toString() returns "Invalid date".so I am not sure how to compare it

Comment: That one works for me too. http://jsfiddle.net/EZ7AP/1/ Which browser says "invalid date"?

Comment: I am using a safari browser ,trying to create a hybrid app

Answer (score 1):

You have date string like : -

```
 var date = "2014-07-02T09:49:49.299Z"
```

You can try  this:-

```
var  getDateString = function(date, format) {
        var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        getPaddedComp = function(comp) {
            return ((parseInt(comp) < 10) ? ('0' + comp) : comp)
        },
        formattedDate = format,
        o = {
            "y+": date.getFullYear(), // year
            "M+": months[date.getMonth()], //month
            "d+": getPaddedComp(date.getDate()), //day
            "h+": getPaddedComp((date.getHours() > 12) ? date.getHours() % 12 : date.getHours()), //hour
            "m+": getPaddedComp(date.getMinutes()), //minute
            "s+": getPaddedComp(date.getSeconds()), //second
            "S+": getPaddedComp(date.getMilliseconds()), //millisecond,
            "t+": (date.getHours() >= 12) ? 'PM' : 'AM'
        };

        for (var k in o) {
            if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(format)) {
                formattedDate = formattedDate.replace(RegExp.$1, o[k]);
            }
        }
        return formattedDate;
    };
```

Now to format the date, write:-

```
getDateString(new Date(date), "h:m:s:t")
```

And to compare two dates try this

```
var date = "2014-07-02T09:49:49.299Z";
var date1 = "2013-07-02T09:49:49.299Z";
var compareDate = function(date,date1){
if(new Date(date).getTime()>new Date(date1).getTime()){
console.log("greater date");
} else{
console.log("lesser date");
}
}
```